# Is Ruby on Rails getting started guide up to date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn ruby on rails from the official website guide, and I copy paste almost all code but some seems not working.
like this on for exemple, I get this error `` undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000cfd0> ``.

```
 <p>
    <%= link_to "Destroy Comment", [comment.article, comment], data:
    {
                  turbo_method: :delete,
                  turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
    } %>
 </p>
```

I use rails 7.0.2.3

Comment: If the link is in partial then you need to pass comment variable for partial like this `<%= render "comment", comment: @comment %>`

Comment: The guides made the assumption you will have a comment instance defined, so either pass it in the partial like Marcin said or assign it as an instance variable on the controller (and then use [@comment.article, @comment]

Comment: Thanks to you two guys, that's works

Comment: You do not need to be that explicit. `<%= render @comment %>` will render the `comments/_comment.html.erb` partial and set the local `comment`. The name of the local is based on the name of the partial. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables